# Working on Three20 Requests with Secure Connection/Signed Certificate

Tags: iphone, objective-c, three20

Do I need additional settings for my TTURLRequests if I have an https api and the server has a signed certificate? How does stuff works in iPhone Applications when dealing with Signed Certificate?
...I really need help where to start from here, thanks

Answer (score 0):

In `three20` library, there is a delegate called `TTURLRequestDelegate`. (http://api.three20.info/protocol_t_t_u_r_l_request_delegate-p.php).
 Your class / delegate need to implement `request:didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:` method to respond back to server.

If your application is communicating to a https server having SSL certificate, you can compare the server certificate received from the server (received in above mentioned method) with server certificate embedded in your application.